# Modifying the program for Larger Input Bounds

Tags: c++, performance

I tried solving the problem given in the following link:

[Spam Classification In Neural Network - SPAMCLAS](https://www.codechef.com/problems/SPAMCLAS)

While my program works for smaller inputs, it fails for inputs of larger values (say, in the range 10^9).

My solution for the problem is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int testCases, i, j , k, l, N, m, minX, maxX, weight[100], bias[100], o, evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;
cin>>testCases; // no error here

for( int i = 0; i < testCases; ++i){
        evenCount = 0; oddCount = 0;
        cin>>N>>minX>>maxX;
        for (m = 0; m<N;++m){
            cin>>weight[m]>>bias[m];

        }

            for (k = minX; k <= maxX; ++k){
                o = k;
                for (l = 0; l < N;++l) {
                    o = (weight[l] * o) + bias[l];
                }
                    if (o%2 == 0) ++evenCount;
                    else ++oddCount;

            }

        cout<<evenCount<<" "<<oddCount<<"\n";

    }
}
```

Is there any way of optimising the code so that it works perfectly fine for larger inputs as well. The online grader at Codechef had raised "Time Limit Exceeded" exception.

I am a novice in programming. So I would appreciate if you could explain in layman terms.

Comment: What about using `long long` instead of `int` to handle bigger numbers?

Comment: Do you understand what ranges of values are supported by `int` versus other integral types?   Do you know what happens if your code accesses 200 elements of an array with 100 elements?

Comment: Use a profiler, it can tell you where most time is spent. BTW: One improvement would be not having to variables `i` of which one isn't even used.

Comment: @user9212993 I think the problem is with performance. It takes a lot of time to process larger values.

Comment: @Peter I could change the size of the array and convert int to long long. But, is there any other way of doing this, perhaps something like using another data structure or an efficient algorithm?

Comment: @AVPranavPK - My point is that it is better to ensure your code has well defined behaviour (rather than, as it does now, having undefined behaviour) and reliably produces valid results for large inputs BEFORE worrying about how to optimise it.   But, yes, I can see options to reduce the calculations in loops - consider what properties of results you're looking for.